# lateinit property windowInfoTracker has not been initialized error occur

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, dagger-hilt

I am studying with Kotlin and I have not been able to solve the error for several days, so I am asking for help.
I am trying to receive window features from windowInfoTracker method in class injected by hilt and put it into compose parameter, but an error occurs as follows.

```
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property windowInfoTracker has not been initialized
at com.myproject.util.ObtainWindowMetrics.obtainWindowInfo(ObtainWindowMetrics.kt)
at com.myproject.viewModels.MainActivityViewModel.passActivityForWindowInfo(MainActivityViewModel.kt)
at com.myproject.MainActivity.onStart(MainActivity.kt)
```

Here is my source codes.
Thanks in advance.

[MainActivity.kt]

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    private val viewModel: MainActivityViewModel by viewModels()
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        viewModel.passActivityForWindowInfo(this@MainActivity)
        setContent {
            MainScreen(viewModel)
        }
    }
}
```

[MainActivityViewModel.kt]

```
@HiltViewModel
class MainActivityViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repository : MainActivityRepository
) : ViewModel() {
    @Inject
    lateinit var obtainWindowMetrics: ObtainWindowMetrics
    var foldingFeature by mutableStateOf<String>("foldingFeature")

    fun passActivityForWindowInfo(activity: ComponentActivity){
        var windowInfo = obtainWindowMetrics.obtainWindowInfo(activity)
        viewModelScope.launch() {
            windowInfo.collect { value -> foldingFeature= value.toString() }
        }
    }
```

[ObtainWindowMertrics.kt]

```
class ObtainWindowMetrics @Inject constructor() {
    private lateinit var windowInfoTracker: WindowInfoTracker
    fun obtainWindowInfo(activity: ComponentActivity): Flow<WindowLayoutInfo> {
        var foldingFeature
            = windowInfoTracker.windowLayoutInfo(activity)
        return foldingFeature
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is in this line of your [ObtainWindowMertrics.kt]: `private lateinit var windowInfoTracker: WindowInfoTracker`. You have lateinit field but you don't assing any value to it. If you wanted to inject this field, you missed `@Inject` annotation.